# Padding isn't rendering properly for 3 digit numbers on sidebar questions

Tags: bug, design, related-questions

The questions that show up on right side; the padding is fine except for those questions who have a vote count between 100 to 999 i.e. number with 3 digits.

Here's a glimpse of that:

[image]

You can see that padding is OK with 4 digit numbers, but not ok with 3 digit numbers.

Another screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yeah the `.show-votes .sidebar-related .answer-votes` has only top and bottom padding set, left and right is 0.

Comment: Wow! Good catch!